# mongodb not running properly due to recovery problems

Tags: mongodb

How to repair mongodb, not running properly due to recovery problems:

```
    journal dir=/data/db/journal
    recover : no journal files present, no recovery
    needed
    ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address 
    already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
     ERROR:   addr already in use
   ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address 
    already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
    [initandlisten] now exiting
    [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
     dbexit: 
    shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

Comment: error is self-speaking another instance of mongod is already running, kill the other process.

Comment: how to kill the running instance??